# .php files are downloaded instead of being parsed by Apache

Tags: apache2, php, xampp

I have Xampp on Ubuntu 11.04. `.php` files are downloaded instead of parsed by Apache! How do I get Apache to parse them?

Comment: Have you installed `libapache2-mod-php5`?

Comment: As a note, you really shouldn't use Xampp on Ubuntu; it's unnecessary and it often causes problems. Just install the packages you need. This isn't Windows where setting up a development server is complicated.

Comment: This has a reasonable, +6 answer. It's not abandoned and there's no reason to think this is a rare problem or one that is limited in time. Let's reopen this.

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
sudo a2enmod php5
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Post back any terminal errors.

If your using Firefox, you may have to clear your cache as well.